# Reload page on back button press (mobile, safari)

Tags: javascript, mobile, safari

so i've been looking around and i've found several questions which are all very similar to this with fixes however none have worked for me because I think they may be outdated.

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').css('display', 'none');
  $('body').fadeIn(5000);
  $('.link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    newLocation = $(event.currentTarget).find('a').attr('href');
    $('body').fadeOut(1000, function () { newpage(newLocation); });
  });
  function newpage(location) {
    console.log(location);
    window.location = location;
    window.onunload = function(){};
  }
});
```

Everything seems to work fine on desktop browsers however the issue is only on mobile. What im asking is how can I refresh the page on the click of the back button so the animations play each time a page is loaded and left.

You can see what I mean here - [website](http://www.retrogradeband.com)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this on mobile but I know this works on my laptop browser.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var $input = $('#refresh');
        $input.val() == 'yes' ? location.reload(true) : $input.val('yes');
    });
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="refresh" value="no">
```